# Commuting probabilities for a conjugacy class of a finite simple group $G$ which generates $G$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a nonabelian finite simple group. Let $C\subset G$ be a conjugacy class which generates $G$. Let $E\subset C\times C$ be the subset consisting of pairs $(c,d)$ with $cd =dc$. Define the commuting probability of $C$ to be $|E|/|C|^2$.

Is there anything reasonable that can be said about this commuting probability? (possibly in terms of $G,C$) Presumably it's no greater than $\frac{1}{12}$ (the largest commuting probability of finite simple groups)?

Comment: First of all, just to be on the safe side, any non-identity class generates a finite simple group. Also, the computation can be simplified by fixing c to be any arbitrary element of that class. The probability is then $(|C|\cap C_G(c))/|C|$, and this can be much larger than $1/12$. For $c=(1,2,3)$ a 3-cycle in $A_n$, every other $3$-cycle which doesn't move 1,2 and 3 will centralize, and you'll find that the proportion of those $3$-cycles actually tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: PS: Running a quick check of non-abelian, non-alternating simple groups of permutation degree up to 500, it may be reasonable to conjecture that $1/2$ could be an upper bound in non-alternating non-abelian simple groups. The groups $PSp_{2n}(2)$ seem to converge to the bound $1/2$, having largest probability $\frac{2^{2n-1}-1}{2^{2n}-1}$ (again, just guessed from computational evidence, but surely verifiable geometrically).